# Extjs 5/6: event to fire when an item is selected among the already selected items in the tagfield

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I have a tagfield to multiselect items from a store. I want to detect when a out of all the selected items, i click and highlight one of the selected value.

Here is the fiddle attached

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno, but should be easy to find:

- If you look into the generated markup, find that the selected item has the class `x-tagfield-item-selected`.
- If you search the ExtJS codebase for `tagfield-item-selected`, find that `tagSelectedCls` is `Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tagfield-item-selected'`.
- If you search the ExtJS codebase for `tagSelectedCls`, find that it is used in the xtemplate:

  ```
      me.multiSelectItemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
          '<tpl for=".">',
              '<li data-selectionIndex="{[xindex - 1]}" data-recordId="{internalId}" class="' + me.tagItemCls + childElCls,
              '<tpl if="this.isSelected(values)">',
              ' ' + me.tagSelectedCls,
              '</tpl>',
  ```

  which has a function isSelected:

  ```
  isSelected: function(rec) {
      return me.selectionModel.isSelected(rec);
  },
  ```
- Your chances are high the referenced selectionModel at `me.selectionModel` is the standard selection model of ExtJS, so it could have an event [`selectionchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#event-selectionchange). Let's try:

  ```
  var tagfield = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag', {
  ...
  });
  tagfield.selectionModel.on('selectionchange',function() {console.log('selectionchange')});
  ```

  Works.

Comment: Thanks..That is awesome!! :)

Comment: I have a follow up  question, suppose I want to show tooltip on each selected item,how would i do that?